# OLS with regression with a constant predictor

Tags: r, regression, least-squares

Imagine for the sake of simplicity that I am regressing $Y$ on $X$  with the model

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$

Now imagine that observations on my $X$ are constant, e.g. take $Y = \{2, 7, 9\}$ and $X = \{3, 3, 3\}$. In this case, I am regressing $Y$ against a constant predictor. What is the statistical implication of this? Specifically, which of the assumptions of OLS am I breaking and Y does `lm` function in R produce `NA`s for the estimate of the coefficient $\beta_1$.

Comment: In this case, the model is non-identifiable. In other words, what can be estimated is $\beta_0 + 3\beta_1$, neither $\beta_0$ nor $\beta_1$ can be unambiguously estimated.

Comment: A more thorough discussion on a relevant [topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319117/a-problem-on-estimability-of-parameters/319162#319162).

Answer (score 0):

The estimated coefficient $\hat{\beta}_1$ is calculated as follows (using `lm`):

$$ \hat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$

You will get 0 in the denominator for constant x, and the fraction is not defined, so R gives you a `NA` output.

Comment: This is a little misleading, because `R` does estimate $\beta_0.$  One problem is that this standard formula applies only for full-rank model matrices--but that does not mean the problem has no solution.  In fact, it means the opposite: there is an entire manifold of solutions and `R` selects one (somewhat arbitrarily) from that set.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is not the actually the 0 denominator but the rank that is the problem. But I didn't mean to say that there is no solution.